# How to use Cloudrail with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, cloudrail

I try to use CloudRail with Xamarin.Forms but when I install the 'CloudRail.SDK' nuget package I get the following errors:

```
NU1202: Package CloudRail.SDK 1.0.3 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Package CloudRail.SDK 1.0.3 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
NU1202: Package CloudRail.SDK 1.0.3 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win. Package CloudRail.SDK 1.0.3 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
NU1202: Package CloudRail.SDK 1.0.3 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x64. Package CloudRail.SDK 1.0.3 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
NU1202: Package CloudRail.SDK 1.0.3 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x86. Package CloudRail.SDK 1.0.3 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
NU1202: Package CloudRail.SDK 1.0.3 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package CloudRail.SDK 1.0.3 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
```

Is there a way to setup CloudRail (for social login) with Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: they offer packages specifically form Xamarin iOS and Xamarin Android, but not Xamarin Forms.  You will need to install the packages in your individual platform projects, and then use DI (or some other mechanism) to call them from shared code

Comment: Jason is right, but you might be able to put the common code in shared source project so it just uses the packages from platform specific builds.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Xamarin.CloudRail.iOS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CloudRail.iOS/) and [Xamarin.CloudRail.Android](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CloudRail.Android/) instead of Cloudrail.SDK.